# ActionBarSherlock in Android 4.1.1

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I am using the latest release of ActionBarSherlock which is 4.2.

I used it in different versions of Android devices such as 2.3.5, 3.2 and 4.0. In all these versions, ActionBar appears at the top of the Activity.

Today I installed my app on a new device with Android version 4.1.1. ActionBar is not at the top no more. It is appeared as option-menu and the sub-menus are appeared as context-menu. Do you know how I can have the actionBar at the top, like in the older versions?

Comment: change your targetsdk version to HC+

Comment: ABS does nothing on Android 4.0+ but delegate to the native action bar so any behavior you see isn't likely related to the library.

Comment: I think @Ahmad is right. I have not access to the phone now, to test it again, but my project was on Android 4.0. I was somehow careless in this case.

Comment: Thanks @JakeWharton, I think you are right. Your library is great. ;)